# Passing macro function as argument to another macro function

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS and I am playing around with macros.

I want to define a function returning a truth value and pass it as argument to another function where it is used in an `%IF`. As an example (not working):

```
%MACRO truth(datum);
    %PUT datum < 100;
%MEND;

%MACRO use_truth(table, condition);
    %PROC SQL;
        SELECT *
        FROM table
        WHERE %condition(number);
    QUIT;
%MEND

%use_truth(table1 , truth) ;
```

Where `table1` is an SQL table with some column `number`.

How can I make such a procedure work?

Comment: First, you have not FROM in your SQL. Is it FROM &TABLE?

Comment: Is number = "datum < 100" in the WHERE clause?

Comment: @D.O. Yes I forgot a FROM table. Of course to put the condition inside would work, but that's not a real case scenario, I just want to understand how to make it work this way to apply it to more complex situations.

Comment: To be clear, I would like the WHERE clause to become `number < 100` after compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important thing to remember is that macros are just text substitution, and they're run before any of your code executes. Macros don't return values as such, they just return code.

When you run `WHERE %&condition(number);` (note the ampersand to actually resolve the value of the macro variable) what the proc SQL actually ends up seeing is `WHERE %PUT number < 100;`

Here's how you could do what you'd like, but be aware that the 'truth' macro isn't actually returning a yes/no value; it's just writing that text into the proc SQL.

```
%MACRO truth(datum); 
    &datum < 100
%MEND;

%MACRO use_truth(table, condition);
    PROC SQL;
        SELECT *
        FROM &table
        WHERE %&condition(number);
    QUIT;
%MEND;

%use_truth(testInput, truth);
```

If you're dealing with more complicated logic, I'd suggest looking into proc FCMP. That'll let you define custom functions that can be used in data steps and proc SQL.

Comment: It works, and i understand macros a bit better now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

A macro that is generating code inline to be used as part of another statement can not itself cause any sort of step to occur (Proc or Data)

You can pass a macro name to another macro, and invoke it after resolving it.

```
%macro dispatch (macro_name);
  %&macro_name
%mend;

%macro a;
  %put NOTE: Aaaaaaay!;
%mend;

%dispatch (a)
```